# How to play a song opened from file manager?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio, uri

I have developed a music player for Android and the app works perfectly. When I try to open a song from file manager it opens the music player but not playing the song.

I tried to fetch the `uri` using `getintent().getdata(`) but don't know how convert the `uri` to my required format.

Help me to solve the issue.

Class to play songs

```
public static void playAll(final Context context, final long[] list, int position,
                               final long sourceId, final IdType sourceType,
                               final boolean forceShuffle) {
        if (list == null || list.length == 0 || mService == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (forceShuffle) {
                mService.setShuffleMode(MusicService.SHUFFLE_NORMAL);
            }
            final long currentId = mService.getAudioId();
            final int currentQueuePosition = getQueuePosition();
            if (position != -1 && currentQueuePosition == position && currentId == list[position]) {
                final long[] playlist = getQueue();
                if (Arrays.equals(list, playlist)) {
                    mService.play();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (position < 0) {
                position = 0;
            }
            mService.open(list, forceShuffle ? -1 : position, sourceId, sourceType.mId);
            mService.play();
        } catch (final RemoteException ignored) {
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to play song from SDCARD ?

Comment: @Kate4Help Not only from SD card. From internal storage too. I am unable to convert the uri from file manager.